# shell sort command -k POS1,POS2 isnot effective

Tags: shell, sorting

I test the sort command with -k option, but I find sort -k POS1[,POS2] from POS1 to POS2 not effective

```
$ cat words.txt 
1 1
2 2
2 1
$ sort -k 1 words.txt 
1 1
2 1
2 2
$ sort -k 1,1 words.txt 
1 1
2 1
2 2
```

I think the "sort -k 1,1 words.txt" should return the result as "cat words.txt",because sort just use the 1st column, if the 1st column is same, print by default order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using GNU `sort`, you need to specify the option `-s` for a stable sort.

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.

$ sort -k 1,1 words.txt
1 1
2 1
2 2

$ sort -k 1,1 -s words.txt
1 1
2 2
2 1
```

See the manual page of the [`sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/sort.1.html) utility for details.